# Grouping by Year/Month in RDLC Report

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdlc, bids

I'm trying to group by report by Year, then Month.

My data is like so:

```
ID  |  Date    |  Value 1  |  Value 2  
1   |  1/1/13  |    200    |    300    
2   |  1/2/13  |    300    |    400
```

On my RDLC report, i've managed to group by Month using expression =DatePart("m",Fields!Date.Value). This seems to work how I want it, but it groups all years together.

What i really would like is to extend this to year as well for example -

```
Year    Month    Date     Value 1     Value 2
2013 
        Jan      
                1/1/13     200         300
                1/2/13     300         400
        Feb
        ... 
        Dec

2012
        Jan
        ...
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: You can use multiple groups in RDLC reports, simply create one group that groups by year and it's child that groups by month. Did you try this?

Comment: I made a foolish mistake! This works correctly after fixing it. Thanks